# Does Azure DevOps Hosted Pipeline Agent Have Specific Visual Studio Option? (C++/CLI v141 build tools)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need this option from Visual Studio (2019) installer: C++/CLI support for v141 build tools (14.16):

[image: Visual Studio Installer Individual components]

On this web page, it has links to the software installed on the different host agents, when clicking on Windows 2022 or 2019 it does not show this info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software

for example, for windows 2022:

https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/win/Windows2022-Readme.md

How can I find out if this is installed or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the VS2019 doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools?view=vs-2019

"C++/CLI support for v141 build tools (14.16)" is categorized under "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.v141.CLI.Support" with version 16.3.29207.166

[image]

Checking the MS-hosted windows 2019 agent: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md

"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CLI.Support" is installed with version: 16.10.31205.252

[image]

From the VS2022 doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools?view=vs-2022

"C++/CLI support for v141 build tools (14.16)" is categorized under "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.v141.CLI.Support" with version 17.4.33006.217

Checking the MS-hosted windows 2022 agent: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/win/Windows2022-Readme.md

[image]

"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CLI.Support" is installed with version: 17.3.32708.82

[image]

This build tool is available on both 2019 and 2022 MS-hosted agent, if you want the specific version, another good approach would be using Self-hosted agent: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops